# Adding attribute to object in jbuilder doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jbuilder

While building a JSON response with jbuilder, I want to add an attribute "image_full_url" to each of my Employee objects.

In my jbuilder file this looks like follows:

```
json.branch_companies @companies.select{ |branch| branch.head_company_id == head_company.id}.map{|branch| {
    :branch => branch, 
    :employees => branch.employees.select(employee_attributes).each{ |emp| emp.image_full_url = "#{root_url[0..-2]}#{emp.photo_image.url}" },
    :machine_categories => branch.machine_categories.pluck(:id, :name, :description)
    }
}
```

In my Emplyoee Model I have a corresponding attr_accessor:

```
attr_accessor :image_full_url
```

Adding an attribute to an Employee object works perfectly on the console.

The part I having problems is here:

```
:employees => branch.employees.select(employee_attributes).each{ |emp| emp.image_full_url = "#{root_url[0..-2]}#{emp.photo_image.url}" }
```

I would expect that the "image_full_url" attribute was added to the emp object, but it isnn't. The JSON response doesn't contain the "image_full_path" field. What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help here?

Comment: What JSON output do you get?

Comment: `employees: [5]
0:  {
id: 3
name: "Vanessa"
surname: "Woißett"
phone_mobile: "+49 1721111111"
phone_landline: "+49 711111113"
fax: "+49 711111112"
email: "vanessa@mail.com"
department: "Disposition"
company_id: 1
active: true
}-
1:  {
id: 1
name: "Anton"
surname: "Massner"
phone_mobile: "+49 175655555"
phone_landline: "+49 7116555551"
fax: "+49 711655555552"
email: "anton.massner@gmail.com"
department: "Geschäftsführung"
company_id: 1
active: true
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you will not get :image_full_url attribute in your json output, because serializer does know nothing about it. You can simply check this by doing next:

```
Emplyoee.limit(2).each{|e| e.image_full_url = "asdw"}.as_json
```

As a result, output won't contain :image_full_url attribute. If you want that attribute to be in your final result, add to that next line:

```
.as_json(:methods => [:image_full_url])
```